# Update UserPool Triggers in a Lambda gives error invoking lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-cognito

We have a scenario that needs to update a User Pool triggers from our rest api that's using a lambda.

Whenever we do that, the update shows in the Cognito User Pool panel, but when the lambda is triggered gives an AccessDeniedException.

If i go to the AWS Console > Cognito > User Pool > my pool > Trigger console and save the same configuration, without changing anything, the next time the Lambda is triggered works without any problem.

I've looked into the IAM Permissions of the Lambda that updates the user pool configuration and we changed to full access on Cognito User Pool to see if that solved, but got the some result. Do we need any other permission for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to find what was causing this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=804779&#804779)

My scenario is slightly different, but essentially i have 2 options:

1 - Could add permission Lambda.addPermission to the lambda that updates the user pool.

2 - Add the policy to the triggered lambda to allow being invoked by the user Pool after i deploy it.

right now option 2 seems better to me, so i'm going with this one.

Comment: You are right!
We forgot that UserPool is invoking the lambda function. So it should have the access of lambda function.
#AWS #IAMRestriction